# Compute the characteristic $m$ of the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2,x^3-3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Everything in $(x^2,x^3-3)$ is a sum $p(x)x^2+q(x)(x^3-3)$ for some $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Letting $n$ be the max deg of $p,q$ we can denote $p(x)=p_nx^n+\cdots+p_0$ and $q(x)=q_nx^n+\cdots q_0$ where $p_i,q_i$ are integers. If $y\in (x^2,x^3-3)$ $y$ is just a polynomial with constant term has a factor of $-3$. So, it seems to me that given any $p\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ we have $3p+(x^2,x^3-3)=(x^2,x^3-3)$ and so $m=3$? And if I want to write the equivalent class using bar notation how should I write it? Becauase I'm quotienting out everything whose constant term has factor of 3, then $R= \{\overline{0},\overline{1},\overline{2}\}$?

Is this how one should approach such problems? Thanks!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I believe so, because $3+p_nx^n+\cdots-3p_0=p_nx^n+\cdots-3(p_0+1)$, which is in the ideal.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you, so $3=x\cdot x^2+(-1)x^3-3(-1) $, which means $(1+(x^2,x^3-3))+(1+(x^2,x^3-3))+(1+(x^2,x^3-3))=(x^2,x^3-3)$ and so m=3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez for the helps.
Characteristic of a ring is given to be the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $1+1\cdots +1=0$ (1 sums n times). Lets denote $I=(x^2,x^3-3)$ and $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$, by the reasoning in my question it can be seen that everything in $I$ has constant term divisible by $3$. And now notice that $1+I =\bar{1}\in R$ and $3=x\cdot x^2+(-1)(x^3-3)\in I$. Hence we have $\bar{1}+\bar{1}+\bar{1}=3+I=I=\bar{0}$. Clearly, m=3 because if $\bar{1}+\bar{1}=I$ then we must have $2\in I$ but this means $2=ax^2+b(x^3-3)$ for some polynomial $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ but because $ax^2$ has degree at least 2, which means there must exists some interger $b_0$ such that $b_0 \cdot 3=2$ which is not possible.